# F# expression between vertical bars

Tags: f#

On the below F# guide page, I see this:

"...The body of the computation expression, here denoted as

```
{| cexpr |}
```

, is translated into..."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/computation-expressions

Why is cexpr between 2 vertical bar characters?

What do those vertical bar characters mean in this context?

Comment: They're just used to delimit the body of the expressions.

Comment: Hmm the doc's notation is confusing. Look at real code examples to get an idea of how to use these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation involving `{| cexpr |}` is used not to denote the *syntax* of computation expressions, but to denote the *translation rules* that are used to translate code inside a computation expression to method calls using the computation expression builder.

I agree this is a bit confusing, because the syntax for computation expressions is `bldr { cexpr }` where `bldr` is some computation builder and `cexpr` is the computation expression body - but the `{| ... |}` syntax has nothing to do with this.

For example, consider the first two rules:

```
{| let binding in cexpr |}          -->  let binding in {| cexpr |}
{| let! pattern = expr in cexpr |}  -->  builder.Bind(expr, (fun pattern -> {| cexpr |}))
```

This just says that a computation expression `let binding in cexpr` is turned into
`let binding in {| cexpr |}` where `{| cexpr |}` means that we need to recursively translate the rest of the computation expression. In the second case, if we want to translate a computation expression `{| let! pattern = expr in cexpr |}`, we generate a method call to the `Bind` method: `builder.Bind(expr, (fun pattern -> {| cexpr |}))` and again, we recursively apply the translation to the `cexpr` that follows the `let!` and put the result in the lambda function body.

It might help to see `{| .. |}` as a function `TRANSLATE( .. )`, but it is somewhat confusing because the function operates on syntactic structures, i.e.:

```
TRANSLATE(let! pattern = expr in cexpr) =
  builder.Bind(expr, (fun pattern -> TRANSLATE(cexpr) ))
```